# I'm trying to make a test for myself on booleans. Doesn't behave correctly?

Tags: python

I'm reading Zed Shaw's _Learn Python The Hard Way, _ and I've progressed to exercise 27, which essentially is having to memorize boolean logic "tables". So I decided to make a quick test in python for this, but it doesn't behave correctly no matter what I do. If I put in every right answer, it gives a score of approximately 40%, when it should give a 100. The script is below. The correct answers are [on the website.](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex27.html)

```
import time

Answers = ["True", "False", "True", "True", "True", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False", "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True"]

q1 = raw_input("not False = ")
q2 = raw_input("not True = ")
q3 = raw_input("True or False = ")
q4 = raw_input("True or True = ")
q5 = raw_input("False or True = "); 
q6 = raw_input("False or False = ")
q7 = raw_input("True and False = ")
q8 = raw_input("True and True = ")
q9 = raw_input("False and True = ")
q10 = raw_input("False and False = "); 
q11 = raw_input("not (True or False) = ")
q12 = raw_input("not (True or True) = ")
q13 = raw_input("not (False or True) = ")
q14 = raw_input("not (False or False) = ")
q15 = raw_input("not (True and False) = "); 
q16 = raw_input("not (True and True) = ")
q17 = raw_input("not (False and True) = ")
q18 = raw_input("not (False and False) = ")
q19 = raw_input("1 != 0 = ")
q20 = raw_input("1 != 1 = "); 
q21 = raw_input("0 != 1 = ")
q22 = raw_input("0 != 0 = ")
q23 = raw_input("1 == 0 = ")
q24 = raw_input("1 == 1 = ")
q25 = raw_input("0 == 1 = "); 
q26 = raw_input("0 == 0 = ");

cout = 0

if q1 == Answers[1]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q2 == Answers[2]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q3 == Answers[3]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q4 == Answers[4]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q5 == Answers[5]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q6 == Answers[6]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q7 == Answers[7]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q8 == Answers[8]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q9 == Answers[9]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q10 == Answers[10]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q11 == Answers[11]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q12 == Answers[12]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q13 == Answers[13]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q14 == Answers[14]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q15 == Answers[15]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q16 == Answers[16]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q17 == Answers[17]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q18 == Answers[18]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q19 == Answers[19]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q20 == Answers[20]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q21 == Answers[21]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q22 == Answers[22]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q23 == Answers[23]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q24 == Answers[24]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q25 == Answers[25]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#
if q26 == "True":
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
#

print "Calculating results..."
time.sleep(2)
print """
=============================
    Your Score Was:
          %s percent
=============================
""" % str(cout)
#
```

Comment: Please do NOT put several statements on the same line. You code is impossible to read.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I just usually do this because it's easier t

Comment: @フェルナンド In the example the `else`-block doesn't do anything, so it can be completely removed, saving you 50 lines of code. Also, if you put the questions in a list you could use a for-loop through all questions, saving you an additional 50 lines (approximately).

Comment: As I mentioned previously, I'm new to programming. My main problem is that I'm not knowledgeable about functions such as loops or logic too much, which leads me to unknowingly add extra and unnecessary code. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @フェルナンド I understand, just thought I would suggest it. I made an answer showing you what I mean but if it's too hard then my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

It's because list indices start at 0, not 1. So your inputs are shifted by one relatively to the `Answers`.

You first `if` block should be:

```
if q1 == Answers[0]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
```

and the last one:

```
if q26 == Answers[25]:
    cout = cout + 3.84615385
else:
    cout = cout + 0.0
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, now I feel pretty stupid. I'll remember this next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with indices and hardcoded values you could create a list of question- and -answer pairs. Then loop through the questions using a for loop. This will allow you to add or remove questions without having to change anything else in the program!

```
import time

# This list contains tuples where the first element is the question and the second the answer.
questions = [
    ('not False = ', 'True'),
    ('not True = ', 'False'),
    ('True or False = ', 'True'),
    ('True or True = ', 'True'),
    ('False or True = ', 'True'),
    ('False or False = ', 'False'),
    ('True and False = ', 'False'),
    ('True and True = ', 'True'),
    ('False and True = ', 'False'),
    ('False and False = ', 'False'),
    ('not (True or False) = ', 'False'),
    ('not (True or True) = ', 'False'),
    ('not (False or True) = ', 'False'),
    ('not (False or False) = ', 'True'),
    ('not (True and False) = ', 'True'),
    ('not (True and True) = ', 'False'),
    ('not (False and True) = ', 'True'),
    ('not (False and False) = ', 'True'),
    ('1 != 0 = ', 'True'),
    ('1 != 1 = ', 'False'),
    ('0 != 1 = ', 'True'),
    ('0 != 0 = ', 'False'),
    ('1 == 0 = ', 'False'),
    ('1 == 1 = ', 'True'),
    ('0 == 1 = ', 'False'),
    ('0 == 0 = ', 'True')
]

score = 0
number_of_questions = len(questions)

for question, answer in questions:
    if raw_input(question) == answer:
        score += 100.0 / number_of_questions

print "Calculating results..."
time.sleep(2)
print """
=============================
    Your Score Was:
          %s percent
=============================
""" % str(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Someone beat me to it!
The Answers, is an array. The first element in an array starts with 0 not 1. So you should start from Answers[0] in your if clauses.
I may write the code this way:

```
import time

Answers = ["True", "False", "True", "True", "True", "False", "False","True","False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True","False", "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False","True", "False", "True"]

q1 = raw_input("not False = "); q2 = raw_input("not True = "); 
q3 = raw_input("True or False = "); q4 = raw_input("True or True = "); 
q5 = raw_input("False or True = "); 
q6 = raw_input("False or False = "); 
q7 = raw_input("True and False = "); q8 = raw_input("True and True = "); 
q9 = raw_input("False and True = "); 
q10 = raw_input("False and False = "); 
q11 = raw_input("not (True or False) = "); 
q12 = raw_input("not (True or True) = "); 
q13 = raw_input("not (False or True) = "); q14 = raw_input("not (False or False) = "); 
q15 = raw_input("not (True and False) = "); 
q16 = raw_input("not (True and True) = "); q17 = raw_input("not (False and True) = "); 
q18 = raw_input("not (False and False) = "); 
q19 = raw_input("1 != 0 = "); q20 = raw_input("1 != 1 = "); 
q21 = raw_input("0 != 1 = "); q22 = raw_input("0 != 0 = "); 
q23 = raw_input("1 == 0 = "); q24 = raw_input("1 == 1 = "); 
q25 = raw_input("0 == 1 = "); 
q26 = raw_input("0 == 0 = ");
Questions =[q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q16,q17,q18,q19,q20,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25,q26]

count = sum([3.8461 for i in range(26) if Questions[i] == Answers[i]])

print "Calculating results..."
time.sleep(2)
print("""
=============================
    Your Score Was:
          %s percent
=============================""" %str(cout))
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using semicolons to avoid having to put the code on a new line. It's not as readable and unconventional. I'd also name your variables with `lower_case` and avoid using names starting with a capital letter, since they are used to name classes.